# String replacement in GNU-Parallel when using multiple input streams

Tags: regex, bash, gnu-parallel

I know how to perform perl-style string replacement in `parallel` and I love it, but I wanted to know if I can use it when I have 2 input streams and apply the replacement for just a specific input.
For example, say that I run the following command:

```
$ parallel echo "First name: {1}, Last name: {2}" ::: John Jane :::+ Doe Smith
```

The output is :

```
First name: John, Last name: Doe
First name: Jane, Last name: Smith
```

Say I want to initialise the surname only with a replacement string:

```
$ parallel --rpl "{init} s:(\w).+:\1:" echo "First name: {1}, Last name: {init}" ::: John Jane :::+ Doe Smith
```

`parallel` will actually replace both input streams to generate the following output:

```
First name: John, Last name: J D
First name: Jane, Last name: J S
```

(Notice the extra **J** in the last name).
Is there any way to tell `parallel` which input I want to operate on?

**UPDATE**

Answering my question, I had an epiphany (or recall) and I tried adding the number of my required input inside the curly brackets when calling the replacement string, and it did exactly what I wanted:

```
$ parallel --rpl "{init} s:(\w).+:\1:" echo "First name: {1}, Last name initial: {2 init}" ::: John Jane :::+ Doe Smith
First name: John, Last name: D
First name: Jane, Last name: S
```

Similar to this question, is it possible to use the predefined replacement string as input for my replacement or do I need to create the full replacement from the original input?
For example, can I somehow use the replacement string `{/}` to remove the path and then do a replacement on the base filename without the path:

```
ls -1 /home/user/*_non-important.txt | parallel --rpl "{mybasename} s:_non-important.txt::" echo "{mybasename}"
```

Thanks, Ido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Similar to this question, is it possible to use the predefined replacement string as input for my replacement or do I need to create the full replacement from the original input?

You need to create the full replacement from the original input. You can find the definition in `man parallel` under `--rpl`:

```
--rpl '{/} s:.*/::'
```

So:

```
... | parallel --rpl '{mybasename} s:.*/::; s:_non-important.txt::' echo {mybasename}
```

Remember that `--rpl` definitions can be put in `~/.parallel/config`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but I was hoping there's a shortcut